# How to send UDP datagrams from Windows PC to Raspberry Pi in C++

Tags: c++, windows, raspberry-pi, udp

I would like to send datagrams (text commands) via UDP from a Windows PC to Raspberry Pi. The Windows PC will act as the client (sending the command) whilst the Raspberry Pi will be the server (receiving commands). I only managed to do it in Linux (which I can't use for various reasons) and besides that I could only send and receive packets from the same (one) PC. Is it possible to do such thing, or would their be a conflict between Windows and Raspbian? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in some Win32 manuals. Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is same, how it can be in conflict. Practically, API is close to BSD \ POSIX, you just need make sure to intialise WinSocks with special call and cleanup it at end

```
WSADATA            wsaData;
if( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0)
{
    printf("Server: WSAStartup failed with error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return -1;
}
else
    printf("Server: The Winsock DLL status is %s.\n", wsaData.szSystemStatus);
```

Call WSACleanup();  when app doesn't need sockets anymore (before exit?) There is more to Winsock's than that